# Xaml to Image to print, high quality prints

Tags: xaml, printing

A few questions about printing from xaml:

1. We are generating gif images for printing from existing xaml.
   The gif images are used for printing.
   The issue we have is the images are not looking good after printing.
   One issue is text is coming up blurred when we print on different sizes such as A3 & A4.
   The same issue is with the images also.
2. Is it better to use jpg images rather than gif images for printing.
3. Is it possible to generate emf images from existing xaml.
4. Are there any best practices for printing high qaulity images/print outs using xaml.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.
Please let me know.

Thanks
N

Comment: Can you elaborate about the process of exporting? Namely, do you use `RenderTargetBitmap`? And, what encoder do you use? Generally speaking, PNG format is better since it is retaining all the data of an image with loss-less compression, as opposed to JPEG that uses a lossy compression (but with better rates). Compared to GIF, PNG format is has better compression and allows for 8-bit alpha per pixel (while GIF format has one bit for the alpha of each pixel - opaque or transparent). You can make the exported image a PNG image by using `PngBitmapEncoder`.